# AWS Lambda (Python + Flask) basic functionality not working using API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I am doing a POC on API Gateway integration with AWS Lambda using Flask, to build a simple S3 upload function. However when I write a simple Hello World function using Flask it's failing with below error.
The API gateway has proxy lambda enabled. However I am not sure why its not passing the event.

```
#Lambda Handler is fl.app
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/resourcetest")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

Response
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'SERVER_NAME'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/flask/app.py",
      2464,
      "__call__",
      "return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/flask/app.py",
      2442,
      "wsgi_app",
      "ctx = self.request_context(environ)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/flask/app.py",
      2359,
      "request_context",
      "return RequestContext(self, environ)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/flask/ctx.py",
      292,
      "__init__",
      "self.url_adapter = app.create_url_adapter(self.request)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/flask/app.py",
      2174,
      "create_url_adapter",
      "subdomain=subdomain,"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/werkzeug/routing.py",
      1594,
      "bind_to_environ",
      "wsgi_server_name = get_host(environ).lower()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py",
      168,
      "get_host",
      "rv = environ[\"SERVER_NAME\"]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Function Logs

```
START RequestId: 5c0f26d9-00ac-4901-b224-c56c23fdff39 Version: $LATEST
'SERVER_NAME': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2442, in wsgi_app
    ctx = self.request_context(environ)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2359, in request_context
    return RequestContext(self, environ)
  File "/var/task/flask/ctx.py", line 292, in __init__
    self.url_adapter = app.create_url_adapter(self.request)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2174, in create_url_adapter
    subdomain=subdomain,
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1594, in bind_to_environ
    wsgi_server_name = get_host(environ).lower()
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 168, in get_host
    rv = environ["SERVER_NAME"]
KeyError: 'SERVER_NAME'

END RequestId: 5c0f26d9-00ac-4901-b224-c56c23fdff39
REPORT RequestId: 5c0f26d9-00ac-4901-b224-c56c23fdff39 Duration: 6.05 ms Billed Duration: 7 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 53 MB Init Duration: 292.92 ms

Request ID
5c0f26d9-00ac-4901-b224-c56c23fdff39
```

Comment: Provide a little bit of context about how you are deploying into aws lambda?

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for responding to this. I am doing it via AWS Console. Please let me know if any other specific's required.

Comment: Also, I have installed the dependencies and using a zip file to upload.

Comment: Hmm seems `flask` is trying to get the name of the server but can't--which perhaps is not surprising for AWS lambda functions. Maybe you can hack it by setting the `SERVER_NAME` env var with some dummy value to keep flask happy.

Comment: Hello Andrew, Does that not to be passed from event object to lambda?

Comment: No it is not. Rather you should set the environmental variables for lambda functions in whichever way you set up the lambda function in the first place as a configurable option. If you used the AWS Console (meaning you used your web browser), go to your lambda functions page and set env vars there. If you used an IAC language like CloudFormation or Terraform, you configure the env vars for the lambda in the templates that define your lambda function and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at error logs you should set the SERVER_NAME value in your code by adding it as a environment variable or insert these details in your handler code to fix the issue